# “Was müssen Sie alles tun?” – meaning of “alles tun”

Tags: meaning

> Was müssen Sie alles tun?

I am confused by *alles tun.* I know that *tun* means *to do* and *alles* means *everything* or *all*.

From this I would arrive at:

> What you must do all?

But that doesn’t make sense to me.

Comment: _What you must do all?_ is wrong, isn't it? "Müssen" in English is "have to", not "must". Am I right?

Comment: @Iris, both "must" and "have to" express an imperative. Depending on context & emphasis, they're fairly interchangeable, though "must" indicates a stronger obligation: "I have to go shopping today." ... "I *must* go right now!" ... "Wow, I *have to* try that!" Essentially the same, but it sounds odd to use "must" with a mundane chore, e.g. "I must buy eggs and cheese" (what, for the good of humanity? why so serious?).

Answer (score 7):

Consider the question without *alles.*

> "Was müssen Sie [alles] tun?"

What ... must ... you (singular formal) ... [everything] ... do?

> What must you do?

The *alles* implies that there are several unnamed things you could potentially list. The person asking expects you to describe some of these things.

Your specific answer depends on the situation, but in general could look like this:

> Ich muss [task1 + verb], [task2 + verb], and [task3 + verb].

The answer does not have be a complete, numbered list of literally *everything*, but a general sample of some of the many things you must do.

Answer (score 2):

This is informal speech. It comes down to "what are all the things you must do?". See [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22489/what-does-alles-mean-here?rq=1) for reference.