# What is the meaning of the following question?

Tags: verb, german-to-english, phrase-request, question, past

> *Was hast du da alles gemacht?*

I know that *alles* means ‘all’ and *gemacht* means ‘doing’ or ‘making’, and of course *Was* means ‘what’ and *hast* means past of *haben*.

And how can one answer this question?

I am thinking the question is asking ‘what have you done?’

What is the correct English translation of "Was hast du da alles gemacht?"

Comment: What actually is the question here? You successfully broke the quote down into all its particles and it looks like you put them together correctly. Are you confused about the *da*? Also, you are wrong in saying *hast means past of haben* – *hast* is the present tense of *haben* and together with *gemacht* they form a perfect tense.

Comment: The question is a request for a list of all things you have done in a context that was berumably provided (maybe a project or something similar). You would best reply by providing the list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does “alles” mean here?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22489/what-does-alles-mean-here)

Answer (score 2):

The person wants to know in what activities you were involved in a place you were talking about. For example: "What did you do while on vacation?"

You could reply with examples: "Ich habe zum Beispiel ein Konzert besucht."

Despite asking for "alles" / everything you did, you are not supposed to give an account of every last thing usually in a smalltalk situation.

Comment: Another idea that came to my mind is talking about a former job/employer.

Comment: You are correct. It can be used in different situations. That's why I kept the initial sentence so vague

Comment: sure, I totally agree with you. Just wanted to give additional hints. ;)

Comment: I know, much appreciated! More examples are always helpful for potential readers. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

One may also ask this question to express something like "What a mess have you done?!", depending on the context.